# Zoom image when i clicked on it

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

i am working on a project in which i have to make a webpage of photographs. In this page i have to show multiple image. User need is that when he click on any image it will zoom but that time it alsoback webpage as background.

Comment: This is not a c# question -- you will need javascript or a custom image control to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the image width and height by javascript, change its z-index so that it comes top of everything when user clicks the image. When user clicks the image second time, change its width and height to normal.

Have a look at this [post](http://www.intenseblog.com/design/8-amazing-javascript-image-zoom-scripts.html).

Hope I answer youe question.

Answer (score 0):

try to put invisible Div on your web page (with z-index: 1; display: none;). After Click just put zoomed image on div and make div visible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a jQuery plugin like @Abdul said. Considering the fact that is a webpage of photographs, and design is important, you should use [NivoZoom](http://nivozoom.dev7studios.com/) or my personal favorite [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) .